# (ssg-wsg) How to get TSC details using MS Excel?

Tags: excel, api

I am not a software developer (no coding experience too), and I find difficulties of searching of TSC / course details from SFw website.

I tried to import SSG-WSG's API to Excel by following the API/tutorial:

API:
https://mock-public-api.ssg-wsg.sg/courses/directory

Tutorial:
https://www.codementor.io/@benniejayguevarra/importing-public-web-api-to-excel-no-coding-required-14bzfy4nev

Is this a correct/proper way of retrieving data from SSG-WSG using API? Please suggest if it is not..

Anyway, I can only managed to retrieved up to 10 rows of data (see screenshots below).. could you please enlighten me on how to retrieve more than 10 rows of data?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj2NV.png)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdv7S.png)

Answer (score 0):

APIs can be used in multiple ways whether to be used in Excel (like what you did), Postman, implement it in a software and etc.

https://mock-public-api.ssg-wsg.sg/courses/directory is a SSG-WSG mock APIs URL which only provides fixed responses. To get the actual responses, you have to subscribe their APIs and call to their production base URL: https://api.ssg-wsg.sg

You can find more information in their API documentation [here](https://developer.ssg-wsg.gov.sg/webapp/docs/product/6kYpfJEWVb7NyYVVHvUmHi/group/2reSbYZjfhi3WWeLp4BlQ4/api/4gXYjoXP7AxcwhiPnKB4of/version/mZHIM5IEXo269TMLzmqG)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply/feedback.  So, I should use the correct API instead of mock API.  Yes, I have subscribed to their API (status is "active"), and I have Client ID and Secret.   How can I proceed to follow the steps / tutorial in Excel?

Comment: You may follow here: https://developer.ssg-wsg.gov.sg/webapp/guides/6gvz7gEnwU2dSIKPrTcXnq#4-testing-with-oauth-token